# Save camera roll image to disc in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm using `CameraRoll` to show all the images in the camera roll to the user.  How can I save the image the user selects to disc so that if it's deleted from the camera roll it still exists in the app?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: @Marklar sorry for not responding sooner.  I just added an answer.  I ended up making my own library to save assets to disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a React Native module for saving asset-library:// paths to the documents folder.

[react-native-save-asset-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-save-asset-library)